# Value measures other than P/B

Tags: equities, research, reference-request, anomalies

Price-to-book is a very well-studied value measure. What research is there on non-P/B value measures?

I came across a handful [used by AQR](https://www.aqr.com/library/aqr-publications/a-new-core-equity-paradigm) (Sales/EV, Cash flow/EV, E/P, Forecasted Earnings/Price) but the bibliography doesn't cite any other papers that study these measures.

Comment: I don't think there is a list specifically. In principle any reasonable way you use to calculate a fundamental value of a security is a value measure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a very good paper that summarizes the empirical evidence on other measures of value is the [Lettau and Wachter (2007)](http://finance.wharton.upenn.edu/~jwachter/research/LettauWachter2007jf.pdf). Take a look at their tables 1, 2 and 3 for the most standard uses of value measures which indeed match with AQRs measures.

Below their table 1, just for completeness:

[image]